# Yii how to redirect to hash link form controller?

Tags: redirect, yii

I'm working on YII framework. I've code form where I've to redirect to the page and in the page I've a grid view. I want to redirect to that hash link which will directly to take them to the grid. Because actually the changes are made to the grid.

```
$this->redirect(array('user/view','id'=>$mIntUserId));
```

How can I add a hash link to the existing URL `#userList`.

Comment: I don't know how `yii` works, but couldn't you use a normal PHP redirect function?

Comment: Thanks but who will generate URLs for me? I want to use full functionality of YII.

Comment: As I said, I don't quite know how Yii works. If there are variables, you might be able to use Yii to store it, then redirect to the variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url)

> Tip: In order to generate URL with a hashtag, for example
>   /index.php?r=post/read&id=100#title, you need to specify parameter
>   named # using
>   $this->createUrl('post/read',array('id'=>100,'#'=>'title')).

So in your case

```
$this->redirect(array('user/view','id'=>$mIntUserId,'#'=>'userList'));
```